# Why does the Doppler effect have different expressions for a moving source and a moving observer if movement is relative?

Tags: doppler-effect

Why does the Doppler effect have different expressions for a moving source and a moving observer if movement is relative? Shouldn't the expressions for a source coming closer to the observer and the observer coming closer to the source, for example, be the same?

Comment: The medium is moving in one case and not the other...

Comment: The medium is moving? What do you mean? Isn't it the source that is moving and observer?

Comment: In the reference frame of the observer, it's the medium that's moving.

Comment: It might help to clarify that the Doppler shift for waves that propagate in a medium depends on the motion of both source and observer relative the medium. The Doppler shift for light (which does not propagate in a medium) depends only on the relative motion of the source and observer, and so it agrees with your intuition.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the Doppler effect have different expressions for a moving source and a moving observer

It does not, *simplifications* of the effect may have such expressions. The full form requires the velocity of the source and observer *relative to the medium*.

I am sure you have seen this in "real life". You have heard the sound of a siren as it passes you. Have you heard that same thing in a strong wind?

Comment: I think this answer would be stronger if you actually showed the equations you are referring to.

Comment: I would like to see them too. A possible link to a derivation would be nice too. Thank you.